# screen generator for sencha touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

Does anybody know of any open source project that can be used to create sencha touch screens?

We have the requirement to come up with a cms(content management system) kind of system for sencha touch application.

What we need is a basic screen generator based on drag and drop wysiwyg editor.

We know sencha architect is there for the purpose but we need a web based solution for this, something that we can modify for our own needs.

If its a node.js based project then its even better.

Comment: So... you want a free and open-source version of Sencha Architect?

Comment: yes... a web based version done via javascript/Ext.js itself

Comment: Good luck with that, I doubt anything exists. Building one might even violate every license from Sencha.

Comment: hmmm... good to know that there is a license restriction on that before we started.. Thank you arthur

Comment: Conceivably you could get an OEM license or some other modification, but you'll have to go through Sencha and inevitably pay them for that privilege. *IF* they let you!